# Check return of sql command in c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I want to check if my query returns any value or not and write the remaining logic accordingly.

```
SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("Select * from phc.userbase where [user]='@Username' and [password]='@password'", myConnection);
```

I want to know this command returns null or not. I tried

```
myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
bool rd = myReader.Read();

if rd==false
```

but I can't get it working. Any ideas?

Here are my parameters:

```
SqlParameter myParam = new SqlParameter("@Username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
myParam.Value = usr;

SqlParameter myParam2 = new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 25);
myParam2.Value = pass;
```

Comment: So... you're storing passwords as plain text in the database? That is ***not good***. Also, it isn't clear if you are parameterizing that correctly - the parameters should probably not be in quotes.

Comment: @MarcGravell this is just a dummy demo.I plan to use MD5 encryption later.

Comment: To clarify: at the moment you are searching for a user called `'@Username'` with a password of `'@Password'` - which is very different to checking whether they have a username the same as the value of the parameter `@Username`. I bet that query always returns zero rows, right?

Comment: @MarcGravell yep.Been stuck on this for hours.Any ideas?

Comment: yes; as I've already mentioned twice: take the quotes away. The quotes are wrong here. Should be `[user] = @Username and [password] = @password` - look - no quotes!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends what you mean by `null` here; do you mean "no rows" ? If so:

```
using(var myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader()) {
    if(myReader.Read()) {
      // at least 1 row; can now check columns
    } else {
      // no rows
    }
}
```

To be honest, though, you could probably change that to `SELECT 1 ...` and use `ExecuteScalar` - much less bother.

In this case, though, it is probably easier to just `SELECT 1 ...rest of query...` and use:

```
object value = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
if(value != null) { ... got a row ...}
```

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction with the execute scalar

Answer (score 2):

use [SqlDataReader.HasRows()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.hasrows.aspx)

```
if (myReader.HasRows())
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: I just want to know if my query returns a value or not.forgive me if i'm wrong but,wouldn't  this check for values inside a table?

Comment: @deception1 your query has a filter; it will only `HasRows()` if your query finds a match